# Can questions go into limbo when its migrated (rejected) and on hold?

Tags: support, bug, migration, help-center

I have a question that was originally in *codereview* and now its migrated here where its on hold.

The problem is that in *programmers* its too opinionated and thus on hold. However I cannot edit it because it has to be edited in *codereview* where it does not exist anymore. The question is basically: "here is how I did it, how should I have done it."

Is there something that I am missing or is the question permanently locked beyond repair.

The question at hand is:

[what-is-the-simplest-human-readable-configuration-file-format](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141556/what-is-the-simplest-human-readable-configuration-file-format)

(situation on 12:51 EST)

Comment: A Programmers mod can unlock the Progs version of your question if you were looking to edit it and make it less opinion based.  The main problem with your current question is that there's no problem to solve.  Asking for "better" implies that something isn't working the way you need it to.  Explain what's wrong with the current implementation, and that should lead to making the question less opinionated.

Comment: And the short answer is "yes, questions can go into limbo (locked) when the migration is rejected."

Comment: @GlenH7 probably this very meta post makes a room to draft the planned improvement. Eg, OP could post here (in question or in self-answer) how they plan to edit, and if community finds the improvement sufficient to unlock and reopen, the rest would be really easy - mod flag with the reference to related meta post and voila (I did [something like this](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/what-is-not-constructive/3811#comment10563_3811 "example") in the past, worked for me)

Comment: I would also note that trying to make it less opinionated would likely invalidate some, if not all of the answers (which are answering the poll of "which is the simplest configuration file").  This makes it significantly more difficult to rewrite the existing question.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the question to this format:

> What alternatives there are for simple human readable configuration file in python? 
>   What are the pros and cons for each solution? Here is an example of a configuration file and how its handled in python.

And after this copy and paste from the original question the two code blocks. The new question matches the answers already given.

At the end add the sentece "note that this question has been heavily modified" and link here.

How does that sound like?

Comment: _pros and cons_ part won't fly I am afraid, see [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260) Upon re-checking, question text looks worth keeping, with as little changes as possible. Title doesn't feel okay, did you consider making it closer match question text? Like "Configuration file format to get XML type of behavior and avoid XML as long as possible" (such a title would probably invalidate all but two top voted answers though, because other answers seem to just ignore what in the text and focus solely on "simplest" title)